# Replaying stored data at a fixed rate

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, io, locking

I am working on a problem where I want to replayed data stored in a file at a specified rate.

For Eg: 25,000 records/second.

The file is in ascii format. Currently, I read each line of the file and apply a regex to 
extract the data. 2- 4 lines make up a record. I timed this operation and it takes close to 
15 microseconds for generating each record.

The time taken to publish each record is 6 microseconds.

If I perform the reading and writing sequentially, then I would end up with 21 microseconds to publish each record. So effectively, this means my upper bound is ~47K records per second.

If I decide to multi thread the reading and writing then I will be able to send out a packet every 9 microsecond ( neglecting the locking penalty since reader and writer share the same Q ) which gives a throughput of 110K ticks per second.

Is my previous design correct ?

What kind of Queue and locking construct has minimum penalty when a single producer and consumer share a queue ?

If I would like to scale beyond this what's the best approach ?

My application is in C++

Answer (score 1):

If it takes 15uS to read/prepare a record then your maximum throughput will be about 1sec/15uSec = 67k/sec. You can ignore the 6uSec part as the single thread reading the file cannot generate more records than that. (try it, change the program to only read/process and discard the output) not sure how you got 9uS.

To make this fly beyond 67k/sec ...

A) estimate the maximum records per second you can read from the disk to be formatted. While this depends on hardware a lot, a figure of 20Mb/sec is typical for an average laptop. This number will give you the upper bound to aim for, and as you get close you can ease off trying.

B) create a single thread just to read the file and incur the IO delay. This thread should write to large preallocated buffers, say 4Mb each.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer for a way of managing these. You are looking to hold maybe 1000 records per buffer (guess, but not just 8 ish records!) pseudo code:

```
   while not EOF
     Allocate big buffer
     While not EOF and not buffer full
          Read file using fgets() or whatever
          Apply only very small preprocessing, ideally none
          Save into buffer
     Release buffer for other threads
```

C) create another thread ( or several if the order of records is not important) to process a ring buffer when it is full, your regex step. This thread in turn writes to another set of output ring buffers (tip, keep the ring buffer control structures apart in memory)

```
    While run-program
        Wait/get an input buffer to process, semaphores/mutex/whatever you prefer
        Allocate output buffer
        Process records from input buffer,
           Place result in output buffer
        Release output buffer for next thread
        Release input buffer for reading thread
```

D) create you final thread to consume the data.  It isn't clear if this output is being written to disk or network, so this might affect the disk reading thread.

```
    Wait/get input buffer from processed records pool
    Output records to wherever
    Return buffer to processed records pool
```

Notes.
Preallocate all buffers and pass them back to where they came from.  Eg you might have 4 buffers between file reading thread and processing threads, when all 4 are infuse, the file reader waits for one to be free, it doesn't just allocate new buffers.
 Try not to memset() buffers if you can avoid it, waste of memory bandwidth.
You won't need many buffers, 6? Per ring buffer?

The system will auto tune to slowest thread ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_constraints ) so if you can read and prepare data faster than you want to output it, all the buffers will fill up and everything will pause except the output.

As the threads are passing reasonable amounts of data each sync point, the overhead of this will not matter too much.

The above design is how some of my code reads CSV files as quick as possible, basically it all comes to to input IO bandwidth as limiting factor.

Comment: Awesome! This is great. Is your code open source ? Could you point me to it if so ?

Comment: Question about B) and C) 

Are you saying that we read a block of data of 4mb and store it in preallocated buffers followed by reading the buffers to convert the data to records  and another thread to actually send the records ?

Comment: Have updated reply with pseudo code, just quite hard to do via iPad. Code isn't open source, but might be able to prune out just the key sections, will check and advise.  It is windows C++ though, although pretty easy to see unix equivalents (althougth I might need to remove the overlapping IO section where it issues multiple asynchronous IO for disk reading, that is windows specific)

Comment: Thank a ton for the pseudo code. It would great if you can prune out code and link to it.

Comment: Had to rewrite quite a bit as lots of included classes. Cannot see where to upload examples on SO, so is online at http://www.fieldpine.com/labs/performance/default.htm sorry about poor grammar